# django no reverse match with filtered ListView

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I have solved this issue now, here is what I needed to do, I have left my original question unedited below. So my original view was fine, though I have added a try except block so as to be able to filter for all:

```
class ProjectListView(ListView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        try:
            self.area = get_object_or_404(Area, name=self.kwargs['area'])
        except:
            return Project.objects.all()
        return Project.objects.filter(area=self.area)
```

I couldn't tell you if this is good practice or not, but it worked. So next, I had to alter my urls.py file, because my "project-create" url just so happened to match my "project-list" url, this was fixed by adding "list/" to my project-list:

```
urlpatterns = [
     path('list/<area>/', ProjectListView.as_view(), name='project-list'),
     path('project-create/',
          ProjectCreateView.as_view(), name='project-create'),
     path('<slug:slug>/update/', project_update_view, name='project-update'),
     path('search/', search, name='search'),
]
```

finally in my template, I have a dropdown which does the filtering, it is unfortunately a little ugly, but that is because I am using a related_name in a ForeignKey, but it works:

```
<form method="GET">
        <fieldset>
          <p>
            <label>Area</label>
            <select name="select-area" onchange="location = this.value;">
              <option value="#">Select</option>
              <option value="{% url 'project-list' "All" %}">All</option>
              <option value="{% url 'project-list' "Digital" %}">Digital</option>
              <option value="{% url 'project-list' "Uplink" %}">Uplink</option>
              <option value="{% url 'project-list' "DTH VoD" %}">DTH VoD</option>
              <option value="{% url 'project-list' "Interactive" %}">Interactive</option>
              <option value="{% url 'project-list' "OTT Streaming" %}">OTT Streaming</option>
              <option value="{% url 'project-list' "OTT VoD" %}">OTT VoD</option>
              <option value="{% url 'project-list' "OTT Platform" %}">OTT Platform</option>
              <option value="{% url 'project-list' "Operational Improvement" %}">Operational Improvement</option>
              <option value="{% url 'project-list' "Archive" %}">Archive</option>
            </select>
          </p>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
```

A quick point on this the first option is because the dropdown defaults to the first option on executing the dropdown item, not ideal but it works. The second item specifically uses "All" just because I will never have that in my database, it is designed to trigger the try except block in the view. Hope this helps someone somewhere.

MY ORIGINAL QUESTION STARTS HERE: 
I'm trying to work out how to pass a url from the template now that I have set up a filter on a `ListView`. Here is the view where I am overriding `get_queryset()` to filter for the `area` attribute of my `Project` model. This works well, however, before setting up the filtering, everything worked nicely, but of course now that I have a dynamic variable added to the url, the reverse lookup no longer works.

In an ideal world it would pass something that would get the unfiltered list view, as I also need this for the dropdown links.

Here is my view:

```
class ProjectListView(ListView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.area = get_object_or_404(Area, name=self.kwargs['area'])
        return Project.objects.filter(area=self.area)
```

and here is my urls for this app:

```
urlpatterns = [
     path('<area>/', ProjectListView.as_view(), name='project-list'),
     path('project-create/',
          ProjectCreateView.as_view(), name='project-create'),
     path('<slug:slug>/update/', project_update_view, name='project-update'),
     path('search/', search, name='search'),
]
```

here is the url in the template:

```
<a href="{% url 'project-list' %}">
    <h2>Service Integration Development Project Portal</h2>
</a>
```

Which no longer works as it is expecting 'area' in some way.

here is the error I am getting:

```
NoReverseMatch at /si/Operational Improvement/

Reverse for 'project-list' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['si/(?P<area>[^/]+)/$']

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/si/Operational%20Improvement/
Django Version:     2.2.1
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    

Reverse for 'project-list' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['si/(?P<area>[^/]+)/$']

Exception Location:     /Users/me/anaconda3/envs/django_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 668
Python Executable:  /Users/me/anaconda3/envs/django_env/bin/python
Python Version:     3.7.3
Python Path:    

['/Users/me/Documents/Python/pcc_django',
 '/Users/me/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.9.34474/pythonFiles',
 '/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/django_env/lib/python37.zip',
 '/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/django_env/lib/python3.7',
 '/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/django_env/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/django_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages']

Server time:    Thu, 5 Sep 2019 09:52:37 +0000
Error during template rendering

In template /Users/me/Documents/Python/pcc_django/project_portal/templates/project_portal/base.html, error at line 60
Reverse for 'project-list' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['si/(?P<area>[^/]+)/$']
```

What should I be passing in the url to get 'all' and not just the filtered 'area'?

Comment: It expects a value for the `<area>` pattern, so you will need to make another `path(..)`.

Comment: How do you do that, as having two urls pointing at the same place does not seem to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you define the URL as (note that it expects a value for `area` in the URL):

```
path('<area>/', ProjectListView.as_view(), name='project-list'),
```

but in your template you call it without a value for `area` (actually, you pass no other arguments to the `url` tag):

```
<a href="{% url 'project-list' %}">
```

---

**Solution 1:** pass an `area` to your `url` tag, like this

```
// assuming that 'area' is an instance of the model 'Area'
<a href="{% url 'project-list' area.name %}">
```

---

**Solution 2:** add a URL without `area`

```
path('', ProjectListView.as_view(), name='project-list'),
path('<area>/', ProjectListView.as_view(), name='project-list-with-area'),
```

And modify your view to handle cases where there is no `area`:

```
class ProjectListView(ListView):
    model = Project

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()

        try:
            qs = qs.filter(area__name=self.kwargs['area'])
        except KeyError:
            # will land here if 'area' is not present, so we return all
            # instances and do not filter anything
            pass

        return qs
```

And in your template can have both now links now

```
<a href="{% url 'project-list' %}">
<a href="{% url 'project-list-with-area' area.name %}">
```

Comment: Can't get these to work, for some reason, django templates can't deal with this, I just get "Reverse for 'project-list' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['si/(?P<area>[^/]+)/$']"

Comment: @iFunction note that I would suggest using different names for both paths, for example, one `project-list-with-area` and one just as `project-list`.

Comment: I haven't got that far yet, I can't seem to pass an extra parameter to a url like it says in the documentation, This is unbelievably complicated.

Comment: Thank you, l've sorted this now, my issue was using "{{    }}" not "{%   %}" around the links. You also unwittingly solved another issue I had with the try except block you wrote above. I'll edit my question with what worked, but Thank you very much for your help.